# Pointer back and next for a node

Tags: pointers

I'm new to C++. I'm now trying to create a class with back and forth pointer. My code is listed below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
Node(int d, Node*k = NULL, Node*q = NULL) :data(d), back(k), next(q){};      
int data;
Node*next; // point to next value on the list
Node*back;  // point to back value on the list

};

int main()
{
int n;
Node*p = NULL;  
Node*k = NULL;  //k is back
while (cin >> n)
{
    p = new Node(n,k);
    p->back->next = p;
    k = p;

}

for (; p; p = p->back)
    cout << p->data << "->";
cout << "*\n";
system("pause");

}
```

However, I always have this error: "Access violation writing location"

I wonder if anybody have a solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of the loop `p->back` is `NULL`. You get the access violation because you dereference it. Write this instead:

```
while (cin >> n)
{
    p = new Node(n,k);
    if (p->back != NULL) // p->back == NULL in the first iteration
      p->back->next = p;
    k = p;
}
```